# c++ template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

this might be question that someone asked before but i can't find it...

i have a class in a `.hpp` file :

```
class A{
    public:
        A(){//constructor}
        ~A(){//destructor}
        //some public methods and arguments

        template<typename Type>
            void func(Type t){//do something for numbers}

    private:
        //some private methods and arguments
}
```

The template method should work for int, double... but not for string. Thus in my `.hpp` file, I defined what `func` does for numbers and in my `.cpp` file I wrote :

```
template<>
void A::func(std::string t){ // do something in that case}
```

But when I use the function `func` with `std::string`, the program calls the methods for numbers... So I replaced the `.hpp` file by :

```
class A{
    public:
        A(){//constructor}
        ~A(){//destructor}
        //some public methods and arguments

        template<typename Type>
            void func(Type t){//do something for numbers}
        void func(std::string s);

    private:
        //some private methods and arguments
}
```

and my `.cpp` file became :

```
void A::func(std::string t){ // do something in that case}
```

and then everything works !

my question is, is this the correct way to do that ?

Comment: I suppose second big block is hpp, not cpp? true ?

Comment: yes, i edited that mistake... sorry

Comment: No pb, I just wasn't sure so I didn't edit it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a partial specialization (there are no template parameters left un-specialized) it's an explicit specialization.

Templates must be visible to the code that uses them, if you don't declare the specialization in the header file then code that tries to call `A::func` with a `string` will instantiate the primary template (the one for numbers) and use that, because they don't know the `string specialization even exists.

So you must (at least) declare the specialization in the header in order for it to be usable outsde the `.cpp` file:

```
template<>
void A::func(std::string t);
```

However your alternative using an overload is simpler and is perfectly acceptable. It works because the overload for `string` is declared in the header, so code that calls it knows which function to call.

Comment: if i understood correctly, the header has to contain `template<> void func(std::string s){//to something}` or `void func(std::string s){//do something}` ?

Comment: No, you didn't understand correctly. Those are definitions. The header only has to contain declarations, not definitions (it can also contain definitions if they are marked `inline`)

Comment: but for templates, the definitions are in the header file... right ?!

Comment: and the header files can contain definitions if they are directly given, i mean inside the class definition... right?!

Comment: For class templates and non-specialized function templates and inline functions the definitions must be in the header file.  Member function definitions in the class definition are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is a good approach for many purposes. However, I suspect your original template approach could be made to work too if you add a specialization for `const char *` as well. That way, you could pass in string literals without it resolving to the numbers version.

Comment: no sure i understood what you mean... what is "resolving to the numbers version" ?

Comment: In the original question, you indicated that the method for numbers was being called instead of the one specialized for strings. I could be wrong, but my guess is that you were passing in a string literal? String literals resolve to `const char *`, which is a numeric type, which is why it was calling the numbers method, not the string one.

Comment: like this : `func("blalba")` ? no i passed a string like this `std::string s("blabla"); func(s)`.

Comment: Oh I see. My mistake. I see the problem was resolved in the other answer anyway. :)